# How to get position of custom model scene builder?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I made some new models with a below setup :

```
  this.cubeSetup = {
  id: "AB0014",
  position: [4, -5, 2],
  rotation: [0, 135, 0],
};


 this.cube1.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
  new THREE.Vector3(position[0], position[1], position[2]),
  new THREE.Quaternion(0, rotation[1], 0, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
);
```

I will click on it and display the information again. I tried using getPlacementTransform().decompose But the result is in coordinate x: 0, y: 0, z: 0.

Second question, I load a human model using Autodesk.gltf. Is it possible to replace the dbId of the model? I want to use API id and when click on model will show its information. I've tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the matrix of an individual element (`cube1`) **inside** the model. The model generated using the `SceneBuilder` extension keeps its own matrix transformation that you can read and set using the `getPlacementTransform` and `setPlacementTransform` methods respectively. So if you need to give the model itself a specific position and orientation, set the transformation to the model itself, and not to `cube1`.

Comment: I see. Thanks!. When I use `AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` can I get property THREE.JS model ?

Comment: Yes, this event returns a list of "selections" where each "selection" contains a `model` and the list of its `dbID`s that are selected.